# COUNT BST subtrees until finding specific given key (inorder traversal)

Tags: c, recursion, count, binary-search-tree, inorder

Homework assignment

I need to count how many subtrees I went through (inorder) until found the given key,

for example: if I have a tree, & it's **inorder** traversal is: 1,3,7,8,9,10,11,15,20
when given key:9, I need to return 5, when given key:3, I need to return 2.
I have been all over the internet trying to find some help & couldn't find.

What I got so far is:

(The "FUNC" is a specific function that compares integers or whatever, it works)

```
    void PRINT_KEY_ORDER(PTN TRoot, void *nkey, CMP_KEYS FUNC)  // prints keys place (inorder)
{
    int counter = 1;
    fprintf(stdout, "%d", *(COUNT_INORDER(TRoot, nkey, FUNC, &counter)));   // prints counter which is always INT
}

int* COUNT_INORDER(PTN TRoot, void *nkey, CMP_KEYS FUNC, int *counter)      // counts times until reaches wanted key
{
    if (TRoot != NULL)
    {
        COUNT_INORDER(TRoot->left, nkey, FUNC, counter);
        if (FUNC(TRoot->key, nkey) == 0)
            return counter;
        (*counter)++;
        COUNT_INORDER(TRoot->right, nkey, FUNC, counter);
    }
}
```

this code works.

Counts correctly but for some reason crashes on the fprintf line if I use more than these: 9 3 1 7 8 20

Comment: First, run in a debugger.

Comment: What is `FUNC`'s declaration ? Do you have the definition too ? I think you would want to `return NULL` at the end of the function `COUNT_INORDER`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is correct. Try to go inorder and increase count in a static variable. Once key is found put that as the return variable, otherwise the default return is -1 for key not found.

```
int COUNT_INORDER(PTN TRoot, nkey, FUNC )     
   {
    static count=0;
    int ret=-1;

    ret= COUNT_INORDER(TRoot->left, nkey, FUNC);

    count++;
    if (FUNC(TRoot->key, nkey) == 0)
        ret = count;

    if(ret == -1)
        ret= COUNT_INORDER(TRoot->right, nkey, FUNC);


     return ret;
    }
```

Comment: you can't use a variable in a recursive function, because it will reset in each recursion, I did some changes and got to better answer, but for some reason building the tree with : 9 3 1 7 8 20 does work & i get the right answer but it program crashes if i add some other numbers from the right subtree, i'll update the code now

Comment: you can use static variable. they are not reset

Comment: The count variable will increase at every inorder traversal of a node. And if the key of the node matches with nkey then ret is replaced by count otherwise ret is always -1. Let me know if this worked.

Comment: im sorry, what i meant is we are not allowed to use static variables.. but u should have a look at the edited post again, i found a way, it works.. but i don't get why it crashes at the fprintf line if the counter is bigger than 6.

Comment: In C90 and pre-standard C, you get away with `static count=0;`.  In C from the current millennium, you should write `static int count=0;` explicitly specifying the type, not using 'implicit `int`'.  If your compiler isn't griping about it, you aren't using it correctly (or it is so ancient you should upgrade to a modern one).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I did not compile :)  it is a typo really